# How to print output in Visual Studio Test Explorer from F# and xUnit on success?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, xunit

I am testing a client application that is requesting data from a database across the network. I have studied similar questions on SO, but they seem to apply several years ago before the really good nuget packages of Hedgehog and Swensen.Unquote were available. ( I am a complete newbie to unit testing).

Is there currently a good way, without creating an F# Class object, of forcing xUnit to print output to the Visual Studio Test Explorer without forcing it as an error?

The below code works to print the visits returned from the server, but only if it is "in error".

How can I get it to print the returned values without it being marked as an error?

TIA

```
module Tests

open Xunit
open Hedgehog
open Swensen.Unquote
open System
open Stargate.XI.Client

[<Fact>]
let ``Get Visits`` () =
   
   let visits = Scheduling.getVisits (new DateTime(2022,04,22))

   test <@ printfn "%O" visits = () @>
```

Edit#1
For others who want to do this, the below suggestion worked great for me with the following changes:

```
[<Fact>]
    let ``Get Visits`` () =
       let visits = Scheduling.getVisits (new DateTime(2022,04,22))
       output.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" visits)      
       Assert.True(true)
```

Comment: My first thoughts are ... why would you want to do that? Kind of goes against the philosophy of unit testing. I don't know if there's some functionality like that, but I have never seen it used. It's possible Console.WriteLine will be redirected to your test runner's result output. However, a logging framework might be better if you usually want more than the error messages from failed tests. The output from that might possibly also be redirectable to the test runner's result output, though I prefer to see that kind of logging in a live log console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XUnit supports writing of additional output from the tests. I agree, additional output can be useful to diagnose potential failures, data conditions (for integration tests) and can provide some additional instrumentation in the CI.

Is there a reason why you don't want to create additional class? With such class, all that you need to do is to create a constructor that accepts an `ITestOutputHelper` parameter:

```ml
module Tests

open System
open Xunit
open Xunit.Abstractions

type GeneralTests(output : ITestOutputHelper) =

    [<Fact>]
    let ``My test`` () =
        output.WriteLine("Here I am!")
        Assert.True(true)
```

More information: https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output

I would say that having a separate class would give you additional control over the lifecycle of the resources you utilize in your tests.

Comment: Only that a class with all the "member" statements looks so much more involved then the simple "let" statements (to this newbie) :) . However, the code you presented is great! (I don't remember seeing this in my studies! )  Thanks alot.